# Email address google maps app in a message to the mobile phone?

Tags: android, google-maps, sms

I am creating an app in android -studio , and I have a problem .

The app contains the Google Maps which shows us our location , but what really would make was that the push of a button , our location was sent by sms to a number of mobile phone , it will be possible ?

Comment: can you try to clarify your question. It doesn't make very much sense after 'but'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a demo app and it can:

- Show your current location on the map as a marker.
- Have a button. When you click it, it will create a SMS massage that you can send
  your location via SMS.

Sample code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>,
        View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
    private Button btn_send_location;
    private double mCurrentLatitude;
    private double mCurrentLongitude;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        btn_send_location = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_my_location_btn);
        btn_send_location.setOnClickListener(this);

        long interval = 10 * 1000;   // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
        long fastestInterval = 1 * 1000;  // 1 second, in milliseconds
        float minDisplacement = 0;

//        // Check if has GPS
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


        // Create the LocationRequest object
//        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
//                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
//                .setInterval(interval)
//                .setFastestInterval(fastestInterval)
//                .setSmallestDisplacement(minDisplacement);

        // Check if has GPS by using Google play service
//        buildLocationSettingsRequest();
//        checkLocationSettings();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
        }
    }


    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        mCurrentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mCurrentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mCurrentLatitude, mCurrentLongitude);

        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        } else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }

    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    /**
     * Uses a {@link com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest.Builder} to build
     * a {@link com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest} that is used for checking
     * if a device has the needed location settings.
     */

    protected void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
    }

    protected void checkLocationSettings() {
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        mLocationSettingsRequest
                );

        result.setResultCallback(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                // NO need to show the dialog;

                break;

            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                //  Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog

                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                    // in onActivityResult().

                    status.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);

                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                    //unable to execute request
                }
                break;

            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                // Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog not created
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "My location at \nLatitude: " + mCurrentLatitude + " \nLongitude: " + mCurrentLongitude);
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
}
```

And the xml file `activity_maps.xml` is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_my_location_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send My location via SMS"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

If you want to get the whole project, please refer to [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android).